# JavaScript: keep mouseover until another event triggers

Tags: javascript, html

What I though it could be a simple task turned out to take more time to solve than expected, I'm making a website menu with CSS effects and plain JavaScript (no external libraries).

The menu items are dynamic, meaning that it can have more or less items when necessary. These items have a hover effect on `mouseover` and a 'stand-by' status where isn't.

My objective would be to hold the animation status until another `mouseover` event triggers

this is the closest I have so far:

```js
let menuItem = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');
for (let i = 0; i < menuItem.length; i++) {
    for (let n = 0; n < menuItem.lenght; n++) {
        menuItem[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
            if (n != i) {
            menuItem[n].classlist.remove('hover');
            } else {
            menuItem[i].classlist.add('hover');
            }
        })
    }
}
```

```css
#menu {background-color: #0066cc; padding: 15px; width: 100%;}
.menu-item {height: 25px; width: fit-content; color: white; cursor: pointer; font-family: sans-serif;}
.menu-item.hover {margin-left: 15px;}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div class="menu-item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

My pseudo-code would be something like this (note: I know this is terribly wrong, it's just to take the idea)

```
find and set menuItem
make a loop: define 'i = 0'; while 'i' is less than total count of menu items; update 'i' by 1
— when menuItem[i] has 'mouseover' event then:
—— menuItem[i] add class 'hover'
—— menuItem[i != menuItem] remove class 'hover'
```

I think the main goal of this is to somehow identify a value that is `!= i` (different than 'i' value) so it can apply the 'stand-by' status to all other elements except `[i]`.

So far I tried to make a second loop with `n` value (as implemented into the snippet) trying to identify any other value that is not `i` with no success so far, since `i` and `n` in that loop logic will forever be the same value.

Another approach I made was to make operations like `menuItem[i + 1]` and `menuItem[i - 1]` but it only works to the contiguous menu item value.

Implementing `mouseout` seemed the logical solution, but acchieved an undesired effect since every `mouseout` event from the active item menu resets its `hover` status.

Any help to acchieve this effect (without jQuery or any other libraries) would be very welcome.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but at the moment it looks like you are only adding/removing a class, when `mouseover` is active. Can you not just use `::hover` in your CSS for that?

Comment: @geshode Thanks for your comment, but `::hover` status would only active when mouse is over the element, the objective is to keep the `::hover` status even if the mouse is not over that element until another event triggers. That's why I tried to make it in JS instead of CSS, if you know how to acchieve this effect in CSS I would love to learn from your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? The class `hover` will only be applied to the item which is recently hovered.

```js
const menuItems = [...document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item')];
menuItems.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  menuItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('hover'));
  item.classList.add('hover');
}))
```

```css
#menu {background-color: #0066cc; padding: 15px; width: 100%;}
.menu-item {height: 25px; width: fit-content; color: white; cursor: pointer; font-family: sans-serif;transition: margin-left .2s;}
.menu-item.hover {margin-left: 15px;}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div class="menu-item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

### How it works

1. First, we get all elements with class named `menu-item`, because of [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) but what we want is an array, so here we use a [spread operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert the collection into an array.

```
const menuItems = [...document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item')];
```

2. After getting the array of all elements with `menu-item` class. We iterate this array using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function and add a `mouseenter` event to each item.

```
menuItems.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('mouseover', ...);
```

If you're not familiar with this function, it is equivolent to

```
for(let item of menuItems) {
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', ...)
}
```

or

```
for(let i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) { 
  let item = menuItems[i];
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', ...)
}
```

3. The function assigned to the `mouseover` event is

```js
() => {
  menuItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('hover'));
  item.classList.add('hover');
}
```

When an item is hovered, we iterate the whole `menuItems` array and remove `hover` class from every `menu-item` element (even it may not exit), so this clears `hover` class from all elements.

```js
menuItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('hover'));
```

After that we assign a `hover` class to the element `item` which we just hovered.

```js
item.classList.add('hover');
```

Thus there can be one element with class `hover` at the same time, which is the one we just hovered.

Comment: This is the desired effect, thanks @Hao Wu. Can you please add some pseudo-code or explain further the JavaScript code logic? I'm learning and I would be love to know about it!

Comment: @ermac Just added some explaination, hope it helps you understanding the code.

Comment: thank you for your contribution! I was able to understand and learn the logic of your code and implement it into my project, thank you, I owe you a beer lad :D